# How to disable onItemSelected on Spinner for the first time when orientation changes happens?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have an `Activity` with a `Spinner`. This `Activity` will load information from the internet based on the `Spinner` selection and show it in this `Activity`. When the first time the `Activity` is launched, the `Spinner` will be selected by default. I use `Spinner#setOnItemSelectedListener` so that each time the Spinner is selected, a method which will load information from the internet will be triggered.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String option = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    loadInfoFromInternet(option);
}
```

When the orientation of the phone is changed, the `Activity` will be destroyed and recreated. I've stored the `Spinner` information and also the information I got from the internet in the `savedInstanceState`'s bundle. With it, I managed to save the state of the `Spinner` and the info from internet.

The problem is with the info I got from the internet. When the orientation changes, `Spinner` will be recreated and select an option. This will trigger `OnItemSelectedListener` which will call `onItemSelected`. The `loadInfoFromInternet` will be triggered again. It makes my data which I stored in `savedInstanceState` be replaced.

What I want is when the orientation changes, I want the Spinner not to trigger `loadInfoFromInternet` so that I can show the information from previous state instead of loading from internet again.

Initially, I come up with the following idea:

```
private boolean isNewState = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        isNewState = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String option = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

    if (isNewState) {
        loadInfoFromInternet(option);
    }
}
```

With the above solution, when the orientation changes, the information is not loaded from the internet again. That's what I want, but, when I select another option, the `loadInfoFromInternet` will not be triggered since it's not a new state (`isNewState = false`). This is not what I want.

Comment: you can use shared preference to store your spinner value,you can get that value oncreate method so your value will persist.

Comment: I don't want to store the value of my Spinner selection. I want after the orientation change, Spinner do not trigger `onItemSelected ` because it make the data to be reloaded. I want to use data I stored in `savedInstanceState`.

Answer (score 0):

What you described in your question sounds on track.  Inside your `onCreate()` method you can check the `Bundle` parameter which gets passed in.  If the bundle is *not* `null`, then you can assume that you have saved state for your spinner and you can load that state.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        isNewState = true;
    }
    else {
        int sIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("S_INDEX");
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
        spinner.setSelection(S_INDEX);
    }
}
```

and add logic to `onSaveInstanceState()` to save the index state of the spinner:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
    int sIndex = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    savedInstanceState.putInt("S_INDEX", sIndex);
}
```

Note that `onSaveInstanceState()` will get called each time your phone changes orientation.  All you need to do is store the state of the activity in the `Bundle` to persist it across changes.

Comment: I just notice something. If I make it like my sample code, after the orientation change, data can't be loaded after I select another option because it's not on new state.

Comment: @Sam I don't understand your comment, but I believe my code answers your question

Comment: If I load the data only if `isNewState = true`, what happened if I change the orientation of my phone and I switch to another option? The new data will not be a loaded because `isNewState = false`. Sorry for my English btw.

Comment: I don't know what your intended use of `isNewState` is, but you don't need it to persist the spinner state across orientation changes.

Comment: `isNewState ` is just a suggested solution. But, it turns out there is a flaw with that solution. If I change the orientation, the `Activity` will be destroyed and recreated. Then, the Spinner will be reselected, data will be reloaded from internet/database while I don't want my data to be reloaded because I want to use data from previous state which I stored on `saveInstanceState`

Comment: @Sak Did you even bother to try my answer?  I didn't write it because I think it makes the page look nicer, I wrote it because it should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried it already. I don't have problem with saving the state of the spinner. Sorry to bother you btw.

Comment: Uodate your question with what the real problem is.